# Parameter Estimation Matlab

Tags: parameters, matlab, mathematical-optimization, estimation

I would like to know how i can perform parameter estimation in matlab using optimization tool box for 2 Functions(Input and Output).

I have an  input function which takes in 8 parameters

```
function c = Input_function(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)
.....
plot(t,c);
```

This function intakes the values of t ,a1,a2 and a3,b1..b3 and td,tmax from using and plots the characteristics

The output function precisely consists of same input values with some addition data of  K1,K2,K3

```
function c_t = output_function_conv(t, a1, a2, a3,b1,b2,b3,td, tmax,k1,k2,k3)

Plot(t,c_t);
```

please let me know  How i can obtain Approx estimation of parameters and how i should approach this problem in matlab

Comment: did you read the optimization toolbox documentation? it has very nice examples...

Comment: @Manex Yes, i have but still i couldn't replicate the estimated K values.